# Installing Blender on windows 10 pro reduces UI size

Tags: interface, windows, installation

I have been using Blender for few years on Linux Ubuntu on my Thinkpad and I never faced problem in Blender installation and running smoothly even in my 2 GB ram Linux laptop.
Recently, I tried to install blender latest version 2.79 from blender.org in my new Dell xps 15 16 GB ram with Windows 10 pro. I am facing terrible lagging problems,

If I install old version like 2.77 or 2.78 or 2.76 there is problem like I cannot see the tabs anymore. They are so small that I cannot see them.

I cannot understand where is exactly the problem. I have all the pythons installed properly.
Can anybody tell me the solution. Is it problem with blender and windows 10 compatibility?
I have attached the screen shot,  please have a look and tell me the solution.

[image]

[image: Just took screen shot of the User Interface in blender 2.78]

Comment: Please attach a screenshot that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's looks like you have retina display, that means it has four real pixels in one digital pixel.

Open File > User Preferences

or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

And the very first entry at the top:
Display: Scale

Set it to 2.

[image]

Comment: Thnaks for your reply.  I just installed again blender 2.78 and tried to set the display scale value but I did not get any such option there. Also Dell xps 9570 does not have retina display but intel UHD display. So, is there other options. The problem is if I installed 2.79 latest one O did not get this problem then everything is normal in terms of display. But Then my pc gets hanged. So, I am trying if older version does not have that problem.

Comment: Сan you post screenshot with User Preferences?

Comment: hi, I just added the screen shot of the user interface in blender 2.78. As one can see there is no such option as you mentioned earlier. I think Windows has terrible problem with blender as there are so many problems reported. There should be a manual with blender to reset blender properly after installation to make it compatible with windows. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Blender 2.78.  For me to fix this issue, I had to go to the following:
File > User Preferences > System > General > DPI
[image: DPI setting]
The DPI had a default value of 72.  When I changed this to 144, the UI was way more usable.